# How to make array distinct

Tags: arrays, delphi, distinct, delphi-xe7

I have an array of integer and string fields. To make it distinct I currently copy line by line into new array and with each record I check if the record already exists in new, if not I copy it. At the end I copy new array back to original.

**It works, but is slow. Is there any faster, easier way to do this?**

```
TArrayMixed = record
    Field1: integer;
    Field2: integer;
    Field3: integer;
    Field4: string;
    Field5: string;
    Field6: string;
 end;

procedure TForm1.Button10Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ArrayMixed, ArrayMixed_tmp: array of TArrayMixed;
  i, j, vIdx: integer;
  vExists: boolean;
begin
  SetLength(ArrayMixed, 100000);
  for i := 0 to 99999 do
  begin
    ArrayMixed[i].Field1 := 1 + Random(5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field2 := 1 + Random(5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field3 := 1 + Random(5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field4 := 'String';
    ArrayMixed[i].Field5 := 'Another string';
    ArrayMixed[i].Field6 := 'New string';
  end;

  // Sort
  TArray.Sort<TArrayMixed > (ArrayMixed, TComparer<TArrayMixed > .Construct(function(const Left, Right: TArrayMixed): Integer
    begin
      Result := MyCompareAMixed(Left, Right);
    end
    ));

  // Distinct
  SetLength(ArrayMixed_tmp, Length(ArrayMixed));
  vIdx := 0;
  for i := Low(ArrayMixed) to High(ArrayMixed) do
  begin
    vExists := False;
    for j := Low(ArrayMixed_tmp) to vIdx - 1 do
      if (ArrayMixed_tmp[j].Field1 = ArrayMixed[i].Field1) and
        (ArrayMixed_tmp[j].Field2 = ArrayMixed[i].Field2) and
        (ArrayMixed_tmp[j].Field3 = ArrayMixed[i].Field3) and
        (ArrayMixed_tmp[j].Field4 = ArrayMixed[i].Field4) and
        (ArrayMixed_tmp[j].Field5 = ArrayMixed[i].Field5) and
        (ArrayMixed_tmp[j].Field6 = ArrayMixed[i].Field6) then
      begin
        vExists := True;
        Break;
      end;

    if not vExists then
    begin
      ArrayMixed_tmp[vIdx] := ArrayMixed[i];
      Inc(vIdx);
    end;
  end;
  SetLength(ArrayMixed_tmp, vIdx);

  // now copy back to original array
  SetLength(ArrayMixed, 0);
  SetLength(ArrayMixed, Length(ArrayMixed_tmp));
  for i := Low(ArrayMixed_tmp) to High(ArrayMixed_tmp) do
    ArrayMixed[i] := ArrayMixed_tmp[i];

  sleep(0);

end;
```

**Edit:**

Since in real data the strings are not all the same, the part where it makes distinct array is slower when original array is filled like this:

**Edit #2: (copied wrong code in Edit #1)**

```
for i := 0 to 999999 do
  begin
    ArrayMixed[i].Field1 := 1 + Random(5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field2 := 1 + Random(5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field3 := 1 + Random(5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field4 := 'String'+IntToStr(i mod 5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field5 := 'Another string'+IntToStr(i mod 5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field6 := 'New string'+IntToStr( i mod 5);
  end;
```

**Edit #3: Publishing code for sorting - only first 3 fields are sorted!**

```
TMyArray3 = array[1..3] of Integer;

    function CompareIntegerArray3(const lhs, rhs: TMyArray3): Integer;
    var
      i: Integer;
    begin
      Assert(Length(lhs) = Length(rhs));
      for i := low(lhs) to high(lhs) do
        if lhs[i] < rhs[i] then
          exit(-1)
        else if lhs[i] > rhs[i] then
          exit(1);

      exit(0);
    end;

    function GetMyArrayAMixed(const Value: TArrayMixed): TMyArray3;
    begin
      Result[1] := Value.Field1;
      Result[2] := Value.Field2;
      Result[3] := Value.Field3;
    end;

    function MyCompareAMixed(const lhs, rhs: TArrayMixed): Integer;
    begin
      Result := CompareIntegerArray3(GetMyArrayAMixed(lhs), GetMyArrayAMixed(rhs));
    end;
```

Comment: One way to speed up searching for duplicates would be to write a custom hasher for your record type and store in a TDictionary (where key=value).  This adds overhead to adding entries (each addition needs an expensive hash calculated) but it speeds up searching for duplicates (O(1) vs O(n)).  This would also let you, for the same cost, insert conditionally only if the record does not already exist (also O(1)).  Whether this is suitable for your use case, only you can know.

Comment: Alternatively, a database may be a better store for this information.

Comment: Thank you, but database is not an option in my application. Never worked with hashing, so I'm not sure even where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for duplicates next to the prior index, since the array is sorted. Here is the sorting comparer reused as well.

```
function RemoveDuplicates(const anArray: array of TArrayMixed): TArray<TArrayMixed>;
var
  j, vIdx: integer;
begin
  // Sort
  TArray.Sort<TArrayMixed > (anArray, TComparer<TArrayMixed >.Construct(function(const Left, Right: TArrayMixed): Integer
    begin
      Result := MyCompareAMixed(Left, Right);
    end
    ));

  // Distinct
  SetLength(Result, Length(anArray));
  vIdx := 0;
  j := 0;
  while (j <= High(anArray) do
  begin
    Result[vIdx] := anArray[j];
    Inc(j);
    While (j <= High(anArray)) and (MyCompareAMixed(Result[vIdx],anArray[j]) = 0) do
      Inc(j);
   Inc(vIdx);
  end;
  SetLength(Result, vIdx);
end;
```

---

**Update**:

In an update to the question it is stated that the array is only partially sorted. One way to reduce the number of iterations to remove duplicates would then be to:

- Find start and stop index to items that share the first sorting criteria.
- Iterate among them to sort out duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I should've posted complete code, as only first 3 fields are sorted, not strings. Just posted sorting code in my question.

Comment: Ok, then you can make a subsort including strings among each of the items that share first 3 fields.

Answer (score 2):

- Implement some methods (equality check, hashcode) for the record to get away with a lot of boilerplate code

---

```
type
  TArrayMixed = record
    Field1: integer;
    Field2: integer;
    Field3: integer;
    Field4: string;
    Field5: string;
    Field6: string;
    class operator Equal( const a, b: TArrayMixed ): Boolean;
    class function Compare( const L, R: TArrayMixed ): integer; overload; static;
    function Compare( const Other: TArrayMixed ): integer; overload;
    function GetHashCode( ): integer;
  end;

  { TArrayMixed }

class function TArrayMixed.Compare( const L, R: TArrayMixed ): integer;
begin
  Result := L.Compare( R );
end;

function TArrayMixed.Compare( const Other: TArrayMixed ): integer;
begin
  Result := Field1 - Other.Field1;
  if Result = 0
  then
    begin
      Result := Field2 - Other.Field2;
      if Result = 0
      then
        begin
          Result := Field3 - Other.Field3;
          if Result = 0
          then
            begin
              Result := CompareStr( Field4, Other.Field4 );
              if Result = 0
              then
                begin
                  Result := CompareStr( Field5, Other.Field5 );
                  if Result = 0
                  then
                    begin
                      Result := CompareStr( Field6, Other.Field6 );
                    end;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;

class operator TArrayMixed.Equal( const a, b: TArrayMixed ): Boolean;
begin
  Result := true
  {} and ( a.Field1 = b.Field1 )
  {} and ( a.Field2 = b.Field2 )
  {} and ( a.Field3 = b.Field3 )
  {} and ( a.Field4 = b.Field4 )
  {} and ( a.Field5 = b.Field5 )
  {} and ( a.Field6 = b.Field6 );
end;

function TArrayMixed.GetHashCode: integer;
begin
{$IFOPT Q+}
{$Q-}
{$DEFINE SET_Q_ON}
{$ENDIF}
  Result := 17;
  Result := Result * 31 + Field1;
  Result := Result * 31 + Field2;
  Result := Result * 31 + Field3;
  Result := Result * 31 + Field4.GetHashCode;
  Result := Result * 31 + Field5.GetHashCode;
  Result := Result * 31 + Field6.GetHashCode;
{$IFDEF SET_Q_ON}
{$Q+}
{$UNDEF SET_Q_ON}
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

- Use a `TDictionary` as a HashSet to check for duplicates

---

```
procedure Test;
var
  arr1, arr2: TArray<TArrayMixed>;
  idx       : integer;
  lst       : TDictionary<TArrayMixed, integer>;
begin
  // fill the array
  SetLength( arr1, 100000 );
  for idx := low( arr1 ) to high( arr1 ) do
    begin
      arr1[ idx ].Field1 := 1 + Random( 5 );
      arr1[ idx ].Field2 := 1 + Random( 5 );
      arr1[ idx ].Field3 := 1 + Random( 5 );
      arr1[ idx ].Field4 := 'String' + IntToStr( idx mod 5 );
      arr1[ idx ].Field5 := 'Another string' + IntToStr( idx mod 5 );
      arr1[ idx ].Field6 := 'New string' + IntToStr( idx mod 5 );
    end;

  // distinct
  lst := TDictionary<TArrayMixed, integer>.Create( TEqualityComparer<TArrayMixed>.Construct(
    function( const L, R: TArrayMixed ): Boolean
    begin
      Result := ( L = R );
    end,
    function( const i: TArrayMixed ): integer
    begin
      Result := i.GetHashCode( );
    end ) );
  try
    for idx := low( arr1 ) to high( arr1 ) do
      begin
        lst.AddOrSetValue( arr1[ idx ], 0 );
      end;

    arr2 := lst.Keys.ToArray;

  finally
    lst.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is generally the sort of idea I was alluding to - kudos for making time to type this all up! This is largely for my own curiosity, but some performance metrics would be interesting to see here.

Comment: Early exit in the comparer can avoid the nested indentation

Comment: Also, the use of subtraction is susceptible to arithmetic overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this. You basically create the result on the fly and sort at the same time using a binary search to remove the duplicates.

```
function RemoveDuplicates(aSourceArray: TArray<TArrayMixed>): TArray<TArrayMixed>;
var
  i: Integer;
  index: Integer;
  sortList: TList<TArrayMixed>;
begin
  sortList := TList<TArrayMixed>.Create;
  try
    for i := Low(aSourceArray) to High(aSourceArray) do
    begin
      if not sortList.BinarySearch(aSourceArray[i], index,
        TDelegatedComparer<TArrayMixed>.Construct(
        function(const L, R: TArrayMixed): integer
        begin
          Result := L.Field1 - R.Field1;
          if Result <> 0 then Exit;
          Result := L.Field2 - R.Field2;
          if Result <> 0 then Exit;
          Result := L.Field3 - R.Field3;
          if Result <> 0 then Exit;
          Result := CompareStr(L.Field4, R.Field4);
          if Result <> 0 then Exit;
          Result := CompareStr(L.Field5, R.Field5);
          if Result <> 0 then Exit;
          Result := CompareStr(L.Field6, R.Field6);
        end)) then
      begin
        sortList.Insert(index, aSourceArray[i]);
      end;
    end;
    Result := sortList.ToArray;
  finally
    sortList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To use this code you could do something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button10Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ArrayMixed, ArrayMixed_tmp: TArray<TArrayMixed>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(ArrayMixed, 100000);
  for i := 0 to 999999 do
  begin
    ArrayMixed[i].Field1 := 1 + Random(5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field2 := 1 + Random(5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field3 := 1 + Random(5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field4 := 'String'+IntToStr(i mod 5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field5 := 'Another string'+IntToStr(i mod 5);
    ArrayMixed[i].Field6 := 'New string'+IntToStr( i mod 5);
  end;
  ArrayMixed_tmp := RemoveDuplicates(ArrayMixed);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already sort `ArrayMixed` you don't need to compare each item with each other in order to find duplicates. The duplicates are already placed next to each other. So you simply need to iterate over `ArrayMixed` and compare the current item to the last item in `ArrayMixed_tmp`. 
Hence, copying the distinct items can be proceed much faster and looks like that:

```
vIdx := 0;
for i := Low(ArrayMixed) to High(ArrayMixed) do
begin
  if (vIdx = 0) or // the first item can never be a duplicate
     (ArrayMixed_tmp[vIdx].Field1 <> ArrayMixed[i].Field1) or
     (ArrayMixed_tmp[vIdx].Field2 <> ArrayMixed[i].Field2) or
     (ArrayMixed_tmp[vIdx].Field3 <> ArrayMixed[i].Field3) or
     (ArrayMixed_tmp[vIdx].Field4 <> ArrayMixed[i].Field4) or
     (ArrayMixed_tmp[vIdx].Field5 <> ArrayMixed[i].Field5) or
     (ArrayMixed_tmp[vIdx].Field6 <> ArrayMixed[i].Field6) then
  begin
    ArrayMixed_tmp[vIdx] := ArrayMixed[i];
    Inc(vIdx);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. I just posted sorting code and only first 3 fields (integers) are sorted. So array is not completely sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted the code for your **MyCompareAMixed()** function so it is not possible to test the performance of your actual code including this undefined function, including the current sort performance.

However, since your posted duplicate detection approach is not dependent upon the array being sorted I simply removed the sort from the code.

Without any further optimisation the resulting de-duplication process completed in well under 50 msecs, which is not "slow" in my book for de-duping 100,000 complex items.  i.e. not single values but items that are records of multiple values.

If the sort is necessary for other reasons then you could retain the sorting and optimise the de-dupe process based on the answers given by others, but I would first question why you think the process is slow and if sub 50 msecs really is slow, what is the target you are aiming at ?

It is possible that it is the sorting that is adding the overhead (as I say, without your compare function we cannot quantify the overhead this is adding) so if this sorting is not necessary for other reasons and if sub 50-msecs is acceptable for de-duping this array, then I would move on to other tasks.

Comment: This is simple example, for ease of testing. Average in my application would be around 100 to 10.000 records per array, around 50 fields (mixed) and called couple of thousand times per run - in around 50 different array structures, so 50 different procedures for making arrays distinct. Sorting is optional, since in some cases it's quicker to make array distinct and then sort. Case by case, I guess.

Comment: Just edited the question with array being filled with not only same strings. making distinct new array is much slower.